# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. in carousel image flutter model -

Tags: flutter, model, carousel, dart-null-safety

I'm gettin stuck in put my image carousel from model carousel_model.dart
enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afiCa.png)//i.stack.imgur.com/Qp92R.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CarouselModel`'s image variable data type is String. But reading a map can provide null data for unknown keys(the keys arent include on map).

You can provide default value on null case or do a null check then add into list.

Providing default empty string on null case.

```
=> CarouselModel(item['image']??"")).toList()
```

If `item` is nullable do `item?['image']??""`

Comment: im getting message like this 
The library 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library.
Try migrating the imported library.